# How to pass & retrieve data in gridview as session variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, session, gridview

I have a complaint table in database which display in grid view after login i have already created a session of user name  when multiple user login at the same time simple label session is working but the grid view displayed the most recent user activity (or complaints) means the grid view is not working through session ... I have bind my grid view through Linq query please tell me how can i create a session on grid view ?

*// This code is working //*

> **Login.aspx**

```
       Session["txtname"] = txtname.Text;
       Session["cust_Dept"] = rec.cust_Dept;
```

> **Admin.aspx**

```
if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                Response.Write("<br/>");
                Response.Write("<b>Welcome : </b>  " + Session["txtname"].ToString());

*// This code is working just showing correct name of userLogin  //*
```

*// Now this is my query through which i have bind the data .//
**// This code is working simple but not working on session based//***

```
var test10 = (from u in dbContext.ComplaintComments
              join b in dbContext.Complaints on u.comp_Id equals b.comp_Id
              join a in dbContext.Customers on u.cust_Id equals a.cust_Id

              where a.cust_Id == Global.cust_Id
              orderby u.cc_Timestamp descending 
              select u ).ToList();

 ComplaintsGV.DataSource = test10;
 ComplaintsGV.DataBind();
```

Not displaying any error when add session in grid view . It is working just like the previous grid view display on screen .

Comment: what you mean by *session in grid view*?

Comment: @Rahul its working perfectly , i just want how can i use session and control my grid view when i login with "Ahsan" account it display my session name perfectly but when new user login suppose "Rahul" login it display your name through session but the grid view  automatically change the data and display data of most recent login customer . i want when both customer login at the same time grid view display their own data .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Page 1**

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var rec = (from r in dc.Customers

                       where r.cust_Login == txtname.Text.Trim() && r.cust_Pwd == txtPass.Text.Trim()
                       select r).SingleOrDefault();


            var depart = (from de in dc.Departments
                          where de.dept_Id == rec.cust_Dept
                          select de).Single();

            if (rec != null && rec.cust_Agent == true)

            {

                Session["txtname"] = txtname.Text;
                Session["txtDepartment"] = depart.dept_Id;
                **Session["cid"] = rec.cust_Id;**

                Response.Redirect("response.aspx");
            }

            else {
                Response.Write("invalid");
            }
        }
```

**Page 2**

```
 Response.Write("<b>Welcome : </b>  " +Session["txtname"].ToString());
            Response.Write("<br/><b>Department : </b>  " + Session["txtDepartment"].ToString());
            Response.Write("<br/>Customer ID :" +Session["cid"].ToString());





protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {



            Session["cid"].ToString();
            var customerID = (Session["cid"].ToString());




            {
                var test11 = (from u in dc.ComplaintComments

                              join b in dc.Complaints on u.comp_Id equals b.comp_Id
                              join g in dc.ComplaintPriorities on u.cp_id equals g.cp_Id
                              join m in dc.ComplaintStatus on u.cs_Id equals m.cs_Id
                              join t in dc.ComplaintTypes on b.comp_Type equals t.ct_Id
                              join a in dc.Customers on u.cust_Id equals a.cust_Id
                              join x in dc.Departments on a.cust_Dept equals x.dept_Id

                              where a.cust_Id == Convert.ToInt32(Session["cid"].ToString())
                              orderby u.comp_Id ascending
                              select new

                              {
                                  b.comp_Id,
                                  Ticket_Date = b.comp_Date_time,
                                  Issue_Type = t.ct_Name,
                                  Last_Modification = u.cc_Timestamp,
                                  Assigned_To = a.cust_FirstName,
                                  Priority = g.cp_Desc,
                                  Status = m.cs_Name,
                                  Comments = u.cc_Comments,
                                  x.dept_Name
                              }

                                      ).GroupBy(item => item.comp_Id)

                                     .Select(item => item.ToList().First());

                GVTesting.DataSource = test11;
                GVTesting.DataBind();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. In `Login.aspx` add the following line:

   `Session["cust_Id"] = rec.cust_Id;`
2. In your linq query use `Session["cust_Id"]` instead of `Global.cust_Id` (I assume customer id is of integer type -if it's not then no conversion is needed):

   ```
   // before the query, assign the customer id to a variable
   var cust_Id = Convert.ToInt32(Session["cust_Id"]);

   // the query becomes:
   var test10 = (from u in dbContext.ComplaintComments
             join b in dbContext.Complaints on u.comp_Id equals b.comp_Id
             join a in dbContext.Customers on u.cust_Id equals a.cust_Id

             where a.cust_Id == cust_Id
             orderby u.cc_Timestamp descending 
             select u ).ToList();
   ```

Comment: I have edited your answer a bit. Otherwise, LINQ will try to map Session.

Comment: Great thank you so much but I have changed it lil bit your logic is perfect